# React - Best way to temporarily hide components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm developing a location search feature similar to Google Map's and upon clicking on the location `<input>` box, a `<menu>` component is rendered that replaces the default `<map>` component

I am wondering how to best handle this switch between the `<menu>` and `<map>` components. Here are a few methods I have tried and my concerns:

1. Using CSS to hide the `<map>` component: The `<map>` component isn't rendering properly - the interface appears but the screen is grey. I suspect it's because of too many re-renders which causes the connection to cut

```js
<div className={`showMenu ? 'hidden' : ''`}>
    <map>
</div>
```

2. Using conditional rendering: Same issue, lots of re-renders

```js
{ !showMenu && <map> }
```

3. Overlapping the element using an absolute container: This has good performance, but it seems like a bad practice to overlap elements like this

```js
<map>

{ showMenu && (
    <div className='absolute left-0 top-0 h-screen' />
        <menu>
    </div>
)}
```

I am aiming for best performance while adhering to best practices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Parent Wrapper Component. Wrap both the  and  components inside a parent component and manage the visibility of each component using the parent's state. This way, the parent component's re-render will not affect the other component unnecessarily.Something like this.

```
const LocationSearch = () => {
  const [showMenu, setShowMenu] = useState(true);

  const handleMenuToggle = () => {
    setShowMenu((prevState) => !prevState);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {showMenu ? <MenuComponent onMenuToggle={handleMenuToggle} /> : <MapComponent />}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Additionally try  using the `React.memo()` higher-order component for the `<map>` component to avoid unnecessary re-renders of the `<map>` when other parts of your component state change like:

```
const MapComponent = React.memo(() => {
  // Your map component code here
});
```